# I filter core data but segue to next page not connect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, segue

I want when i click  my filtered table view and segue to right controller ,  but now  only show filtered table view not connect with right controller.

it's app  about calendar , i want  when you chick  date button that will show same day data for you , so i try to filter data from core data ,but segue  not work  , maybe is `fetchedResultsController` need to filter ,  I have no idea what should i do .

It's my filter core data code

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {

    [self.filteredCandyArray removeAllObjects];


    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF 
        contains[cd] %@",searchText];
    filteredCandyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[alldates 
        filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

    NSLog(@"date is %@",alldates);
    NSLog(@"%@",filteredCandyArray); 
}
```

It's my prepareForSegue code

```
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] 
        objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];

    if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSManagedObject *object2 = [filterObject objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object2];
    }
} else {
    AddDetailViewController *view2 =[segue destinationViewController];
    [view2 passData:self.dateLabel.text];
}
```

Comment: What does "segue not work" mean?  (Crash?  Error message?  Wrong data?)  Try putting some log messages in `prepareForSegue` to see what values are and what path the app takes through there.

Comment: <UIStoryboardPushSegue: 0x1f5e9180> and *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: OK, log the values of `[self fetchedResultsController]` and `filterObject` in `prepareForSegue`.  If one of those is nil/null it's a clue.

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController: 0x1eddd480>
fiterobject is (null)
filteredCandyArray is my filter data from core data  , i sure that have right data  , i don't know how to deal with   NSFetchedResultsController  , thanks you help a lot

Comment: i don't know how to deal with NSFetchedResultsController can you teach me ?

Comment: What is `filterObject` **supposed** to be?  Where does it come from?

Comment: I create that  new NSFetchedResultsController *filterObject, I think might come in handy  , and tried to filter fetchedResultsController,but it's fail

Comment: Your code uses `filterObject` but doesn't answer the question about where it comes from or how it's created.  `NSFetchedResultsController *filterObject` just declares a pointer; it doesn't create an object.

Comment: I am sorry ,just declare not create